# Is there any way to retrieve original string from [Ljava.lang.String;@7fe49271

Tags: java

By mistake my string variable saved like [Ljava.lang.String;@7fe49271 .Is there any way to retrieve original string data ?.I am using groovy on grails as application framework

Comment: Did you try Arrays.toString() ?

Comment: this is toString() value.

Comment: Is there any way to get all the _correct_ numbers which formed the sum of the digits of "100"? No, there isn't, like in your case. You can try to dump the heap and search that for String arrays matching the hashcode, but that still doesn't guarantee that you find the correct object (due to hash collisions).

Comment: @Subhabrata Mondal @ Eran  yes i tried .toString() but shows the the same string

Comment: Then you didn't try Erans suggestions.

Comment: yes  @Tom i tried

Comment: @nishadmoideenkutty is it stored in db??

Comment: @ Subhabrata Mondal : yes

Comment: [Ljava.lang.String;@7fe49271 is the result of calling `toString()` on an array of `String` objects. **No, there is no way** to get the content of the string array back from this code.

Comment: @Jesper this should be an answer

Comment: No there is no way

Answer (score 2):

The string `[Ljava.lang.String;@7fe49271` is the result of calling `toString()` on a `String[]` (an array of `String` objects).

The `[Ljava.lang.String;` is a code that indicates that the object is a `String[]` and `7fe49271` is the hash code of the object.

It is impossible to get back the content of the original string array from this code - the code simply does not contain that information.